# Laravel 5 on shared webhosting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have a local installation of Laravel 5 and I wanted to transfer this to a webhosting, however it's a shared one. With Laravel 4 I managed to do this succesfully, but no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work with Laravel 5, I've tried various .htaccess combinations. The fact that path.php is missing from this version doesn't seem to help either..

The problem is that I don't have the classic structure to work with: I can't place the public files in public_html and above that folder the backend. I can only work inside the public_html folder, so the top level file I can upload is domain.com/index.php so to speak.

Does anyone know how I can setup Laravel 5 in this structure?

Comment: Does your shared hosting meets requirements: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation ?

Comment: Assuming your hosting meets Laravel 5's requirements. You don't have to place the public files on public_html, you should configure your domain's root folder to laravel's public folder. So to speak it would be /public_html/public..

Comment: It does meet the requirements and via this way, the site does show on the index, but none of the routes seem to work yet.. This is my .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.html [L]

Answer (score 0):

Update: The issue was that we used a HashHelper service using shell_execute, which is of course not supported by shared hosting. After we replaced this, the site worked perfectly on shared hosting, with this .htaccess configuration:

http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting?page=1#reply-24588

Thanks for the help!